# How to skew View in appcelerator alloy (Titanium)

Tags: mobile, appcelerator, transformation, appcelerator-titanium, skew

I would like to something like [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_transform_skew), can't find any example that uses skew in titanium.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_transform_skew

Answer (score 2):

It's currently only possible on iOS due to the availability of 3DMatrix.

**Try this**

```
var ANIMATION = require('animation');

var window = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    title : "Tilt Animations",
    backgroundColor : 'white'
});

var view = Ti.UI.createView({
    backgroundColor : '#0bb',
    width : '70%',
    height : '50%'
});

var label = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text : 'My Div',
    color : 'black',
    touchEnabled : false
});

if (OS_IOS) {
    view.addEventListener('touchend', touchend);
    view.addEventListener('touchcancel', touchend);
    view.addEventListener('touchstart', touchStartMove);
    view.addEventListener('touchmove', touchStartMove);
}

view.add(label);
window.add(view);
window.open();

function touchStartMove(e) {
    ANIMATION.touchStartOrMove(e, view);
}

function touchend(e) {
    ANIMATION.touchEnd(view);
}
```

- Find [animation.js here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nk1l3t8zvqzlds5/animation.js?dl=0) and put it in Project->app->lib folder
- Now try to drag the cursor or click anywhere on the view and you will see the tilt animations in all directions as your cursor drag on the view.
- So, to completely replicate your question, all you need is just to provide select options and set the angles according to that.

Comment: Actually i want to make view look like this both in android / ios:

http://i.stack.imgur.com/LWZ14.png

Skew 20º horizontal